# Example payment always sets the order to "Checkout: payment"

Tags: 7, commerce

I'm using the *Example Payment* module to test payments for free stuff in Drupal 7 Commerce. It works, but after the last step in the checkout process, the order status is always set to *Checkout: Complete* and its workflow order state set to *Checkout*, even though I have rules in place that set the order status and state to *Completed* (when an order is first paid in full).

When I look at the order revisions, I notice the order status is first set to *Completed* and then to *Checkout: Payment*. The log contains a *Customer continued to the next checkout page via a submit button.* message.

I created dblog messages to show what is happening, but I can't find any message that reverts the shopping cart state.

Comment: Do you need the rule in place? Sounds like maybe there's a timing conflict there?

Comment: @RyanSzrama After removing all my "set order state/status" rules to completed and clearing the cache, it still remains the same. I guess there is no rule responsible for this but perhaps a callback function in the example module or perhaps one that's missing. The last page that the user sees before the purchase happens (it's a duplicate of the example payment module) shows a button that says "continue to the next step". Perhaps there should be another step after this? This button is indeed a submit button but it doesn't say "pay now" or something like that.

Comment: Yeah, no clue; it's a pretty slim module, tbh. I'd be surprised if it was getting in the way on its own.

Comment: Thanks @RyanSzrama for your support. Nothing else happens after this state anyway, I believe, so I'm going to have to set them as completed with a VBO or cron job rule.